# Can we set different thresholds for different rows in grafana table panel

Tags: grafana

We have a requirement to give different threshold for different rows in a grafana table.  Anyone has any idea , how can we do it.

When I use the field override setting, it applies the threshold to the whole column.

[image]

Comment: Maybe Transformation "Config from query results" might help?

Comment: In the above table, for each rows, there is a different query expression. For 4 rows, I have 4 expressions.  Any further suggestion on how config from query results transformation will help . ?